# Laravel 7: Showing error while passing multiple variable in str_replace

Tags: arrays, laravel, str-replace

I'm facing error while passing multiple variable in `str_replace` function.
Error: `Argument 1 passed to Xenon\LaravelBDSms\SMS::shoot() must be of the type string, null given, called in`

Message Body:

```
Hello #name#,
Total Amount Purchased : #total#
Previous Due: #previous_due#
Deposit: #deposit#
Total Due: #total_due#
```

Controller:

```
$id = 1;
$sms_settings = SmsSetting::findOrFail($id);
if($sms_settings->order_create == 1){
    $name = $request->name;
    $previous_due = $customer->due;
    $deposit = $request->deposit;
    $total = $request->total;
    $total_due = $request->total_due;
    $msgs =  $sms_settings->order_create_sms;
    $msg = str_replace(array('#name#', '#total#','#previous_due#','#deposit#','#total_due#'), array($name,$previous_due, $deposit, $total, $total_due), $msgs);
    $send= SMS::shoot($request->mobile, $msg);
}
```

Shoot Function:

```
public function shoot(string $number, string $text)
  {
     $this->sender->setMobile($number);
     $this->sender->setMessage($text);
     return $this->sender->send();
  }
```

Here I'm using a Laravel Package for sending SMS to mobile number. How can I pass multiple variable in str_replace?

Comment: Error in the beginning and question at the end are not related. Please improve your Post.

Comment: Already Updated. Thanks

Comment: There are two issues then. 
`$request->mobile` is null, confirm if you are passing the same in the request. Thats why the error. Also use $request->validated('mobile'), that is safer.

Comment: `str_replace` seems to be fine. [Example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) But Look at examples again, it might break if characters are overlapping with other arguments.

Comment: You are right, I was looking others variable multiple times except this for couple of hours. Thanks brother. How can I accept your answer?

Comment: I have posted my comments as answer, you can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$request->mobile` is null, confirm if you are passing the same in the request. Thats why the error.
Also use `$request->validated('mobile')`, that is safer.

`str_replace` seems to be fine. Take a look at [Example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), but Look at examples again, it might break if characters are overlapping with other arguments

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable `$msgs =  $sms_settings->order_create_sms;` contain empty that's why `str_replace` couldn't replace the data that you given so
`$msg = str_replace(array('#name#', '#total#','#previous_due#','#deposit#','#total_due#'), array($name,$previous_due, $deposit, $total, $total_due), $msgs);` , will return null.
I recommend checking `$msgs` again.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $msgs =  $sms_settings->order_create_sms;
```

Make sure $msgs is not null place is_null($msgs) condition before feeding to str_replace

check more about str_replace: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php